# How to tune the batch size for LSTM using hyperband?

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, hyperparameters, batchsize

I am trying to tune the batch size for LSTM using hyperband optimisation using the following codes, but it didn't work because the numbers of the training items did not change in different batch size conditions. Do you know how to improve the codes? Thank you in advance.

```
import keras_tuner as kt
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

x_train = np.random.rand(63, 92)
y_train = np.random.randint(0,6, (63))

x_val = np.random.rand(63, 92)
y_val = np.random.randint(0,7, (63))

train_set = tf.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
    x_train, y_train, sequence_length=10)
val_set = tf.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
    x_val, y_val, sequence_length=10)

train_set = tf.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
    x_train, y_train, sequence_length=10, batch_size =1)
val_set = tf.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
    x_val, y_val, sequence_length=10, batch_size =1)

def model_builder(hp):
    
    lr = hp.Choice('learning_rate', values=[1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4])
    hp_units = hp.Int('units', min_value=32, max_value=256, step=32)
    hp_units1 = hp.Int('units1', min_value=32, max_value=256, step=32)
    
    lstm_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(hp_units, return_sequences=True)),
        tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(hp_units1)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
    ])
    
    lstm_model.compile(loss='mse',
                  optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr),
                  metrics=['mse'])
    
    return lstm_model

class MyTuner(kt.tuners.Hyperband):
  def run_trial(self, trial, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['batch_size'] = trial.hyperparameters.Int('batch_size', 2, 6, step=2)
    return super(MyTuner, self).run_trial(trial, *args, **kwargs)

tuner = MyTuner(model_builder,
                     objective='val_loss',
                     max_epochs=4,
                     factor=3,
                     directory='KT',
                     project_name='intro_to_kt0207',
                     overwrite=True)

early_stop = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
    monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=20, verbose=0,
    mode='min', baseline=None, restore_best_weights=True
)

tuner.search(train_set, epochs=1000,
             validation_data = val_set)
```

This is the output:

Search: Running Trial #2

Hyperparameter    |Value             |Best Value So Far
learning_rate     |0.0001            |0.01
units             |192               |224
units1            |192               |64
batch_size        |4                 |2
tuner/epochs      |2                 |2
tuner/initial_e...|0                 |0
tuner/bracket     |1                 |1
tuner/round       |0                 |0

Epoch 1/2
54/54 [==============================] - 7s 37ms/step - loss: 4.4262 - mse: 4.4262 - val_loss: 3.4221 - val_mse: 3.4221
Epoch 2/2
54/54 [==============================] - 1s 12ms/step - loss: 3.1213 - mse: 3.1213 - val_loss: 3.4463 - val_mse: 3.4463
Trial 2 Complete [00h 00m 08s]
val_loss: 3.42207670211792

Best val_loss So Far: 3.1889588832855225
Total elapsed time: 00h 00m 18s

Search: Running Trial #3

Hyperparameter    |Value             |Best Value So Far
learning_rate     |0.01              |0.01
units             |192               |224
units1            |96                |64
batch_size        |2                 |2
tuner/epochs      |2                 |2
tuner/initial_e...|0                 |0
tuner/bracket     |1                 |1
tuner/round       |0                 |0

Epoch 1/2
54/54 [==============================] - 7s 34ms/step - loss: 3.6241 - mse: 3.6241 - val_loss: 3.1699 - val_mse: 3.1699
Epoch 2/2
54/54 [==============================] - 1s 12ms/step - loss: 3.1807 - mse: 3.1807 - val_loss: 3.2480 - val_mse: 3.2480
Trial 3 Complete [00h 00m 08s]
val_loss: 3.1699421405792236

Best val_loss So Far: 3.1699421405792236
Total elapsed time: 00h 00m 26s

Comment: Have you solved this issue?